# The instance member 'posts' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter

I would like to load other REST CALL which callS other data from DB.
I would like to use bottom navigation bar.

When I coded without bottom navigation bar, the app worked.
But When I inserted bottom navigation bar, "posts" function(related to REST CALL) has an error.

```
 itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Post post = posts[index];
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'Services.dart';
import 'Post.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter ListView'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late List<Post> posts;
  late bool loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loading = true;
    Services.getPosts().then((list) {
      super.setState(() {
        posts = list;
        loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Posts'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.60),
        selectedFontSize: 14,
        unselectedFontSize: 14,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        //현재 선택된 Index
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Favorites'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Music'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.music_note),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Places'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('News'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
    );
  }

  List _widgetOptions = [
    Column(
      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      // crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Row(
            children: const [
              Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text('Date',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            height: 2.5,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                          )))),
              Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text('Koreanwon/us\$',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            height: 2.5,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                          )))),
              Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text('Koreanwon',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            height: 2.5,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                          )))),
              Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text('US \$',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            height: 2.5,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                          )))),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Post post = posts[index];
                    return Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                      ),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Row(
                          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.date))),
                            Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.rate))),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Center(child: Text(post.koreanwon))),
                            Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.dollar))),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      // ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ];
}
```

Comment: which type of error are shown?

Comment: ERROR: lib/main.dart:151:30: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'posts'.
ERROR:                   itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
ERROR:                              ^^^^^
ERROR: lib/main.dart:151:50: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'posts'.
ERROR:                   itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
ERROR:                                                  ^^^^^
ERROR: lib/main.dart:153:33: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'posts'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're trying to access an instance variable (`posts`), in another instance variable(`_widgetOptions`). This is disallowed as you're trying to access something that isn't. Move the initialization into the initState.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'Services.dart';
import 'Post.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter ListView'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late List<Post> posts;
  late bool loading;
  late List _widgetOptions;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loading = true;
    Services.getPosts().then((list) {
      super.setState(() {
        posts = list;
        loading = false;
      });
    });
    //You have to initialize _widgetOptions into the `initState`   method.
    _widgetOptions = [
    Column(
      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      // crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Row(
            children: const [
              Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text('Date',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            height: 2.5,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                          )))),
              Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text('Koreanwon/us\$',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            height: 2.5,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                          )))),
              Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text('Koreanwon',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            height: 2.5,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                          )))),
              Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text('US \$',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            height: 2.5,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                          )))),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Post post = posts[index];
                    return Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                      ),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Row(
                          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.date))),
                            Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.rate))),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Center(child: Text(post.koreanwon))),
                            Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(post.dollar))),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      // ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ];

  }

  @override
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Posts'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.60),
        selectedFontSize: 14,
        unselectedFontSize: 14,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        //현재 선택된 Index
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Favorites'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Music'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.music_note),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Places'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('News'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
    );
  }

 
}
```